# Do I need to handle chunked HTTP requests if I only work with GET requests?

Tags: http, http-headers, chunked

I am writing a Netty server that handles HTTP GET requests from the browser to serve  scripts or pixels.

My understanding is that there is no reason why I would receive chunked requests as all I need is either in the URI or the cookie but is there a chance a browser would chunk the request?

(I don't even know if it is possible to chunk a header by the way)

Comment: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616

Comment: I would take that for a "no" a header cannot be chunked since chunked is for request body only. As for whether a browser may want to chunk a GET request (however silly that is) I believe there is no answer in the norm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically, a `GET` request could be send with chunked encoding. The body would be empty, consisting of an empty chunk, but the trailer could include additional header fields. I can't imagine anyone actually sending such a request other than to see what happens and I don't think anyone will care if you mishandle it. Standards technically allow all kinds of stupid things.